# Run code after/before adding item to an Collection in .NET

Tags: .net, collections, aop

Is it possible to run code aftter or before the item was added to collection?

Lets say i have object Product with property Price and Warehouse object with properties IList Products and TotalPrice. I need to update TotalPrice each time the collection was modified. I dont want to calculate TotalPrice inside that property each time its accessed.

If it is possible only with AOP, is there any free AOP framework for .net?

Comment: Are you averse to using other list implementations? (for example, `BindingList<T>` provides events that facilitate this functionality)

Comment: I nedd collection which is supported by EntityFramework CodeFirst. I'm not sure if ObservableCollection or BindingList are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at  `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is a collection designed especially for the scenario you described:

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):  *"Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed."*